# What is a neural network compatibility function?

Tags: neural-networks

> Typically, a neural network parameterized by weights $\mathbf{W}$ is
> a function from an input $x$ to an output $y$. The network has
> an associated compatibility function $\Psi(y; x, \mathbf{W}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ that
> measures how likely an output y is given an input x under
> weights $W$.

**Source:** Gradient-based Inference for Networks with Output Constraints, AAAI 2019 (https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.08608)

What is a compatibility function? What is its utility?

Neural networks are generally deterministic. We are guaranteed to get a specific output for a given input. How do we interpret compatibility function in this context?

Comment: What have you understood about it? Have you read the paper that you're citing?